# ObjectSerializer.php Error when using confirmShipment() from jlevers/selling-partner-api

Tags: fatal-error, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to confirm Amazon's orders using confirmShipment() from from jlevers/selling-partner-api as described in the GitHub below but I am getting **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Class 'null' not found /vendor/jlevers/selling-partner-api/lib/ObjectSerializer.php:366

[https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api/](https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api/blob/main/docs/Api/OrdersV0Api.md#confirmShipment)

I successfully create the $apiInstance and the $payload, but when I execute it I get this error from the ObjectSerializer:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'null' not found in /vendor/jlevers/selling-partner-api/lib/ObjectSerializer.php:366 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/jlevers/selling-partner-api/lib/Api/OrdersV0Api.php(92):
 SellingPartnerApi\ObjectSerializer::deserialize(Object(stdClass), 'null', Array) #1 /vendor/jlevers/selling-partner-api/lib/Api/OrdersV0Api.php(55):
 SellingPartnerApi\Api\OrdersV0Api->confirmShipmentWithHttpInfo('114-0297756-279...', Object(SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentRequest)) #2 /amazon_settings.php(457):
 SellingPartnerApi\Api\OrdersV0Api->confirmShipment('114-0297756-279...', Object(SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentRequest)) #3 /scripts/test.php(65):
 Amazon->fn_confirmShipment('/home/scripts...') #4 {main} thrown in /vendor/jlevers/selling-partner-api/lib/ObjectSerializer.php on line 366
```

This is what I am using:

```php
$apiInstance = new SellingPartnerApi\Api\OrdersV0Api($config);
$order_id = 'order_id_example'; // string | An Amazon-defined order identifier, in 3-7-7 format (correct order number being passed).
$payload = new \SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentRequest(); // \SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentRequest | Request body of confirmShipment.

try {
    $apiInstance->confirmShipment($order_id, $payload);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling OrdersV0Api->confirmShipment: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

This is the $payload that ConfirmShipmentRequest generates:

```php
SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentRequest Object
(
    [container:protected] => Array
        (
            [package_detail] => Array
                (
                    [package_reference_id] => 2790602
                    [carrier_code] => FedEx
                    [shipping_method] => Ground
                    [tracking_number] => 63828440XXX
                    [ship_date] => 2023-11-07T07:17:07-00:00
                    [order_items] => Array
                        (
                            [order_item_id] => 87699213804801
                            [quantity] => 4
                        )

                )

            [cod_collection_method] => 
            [marketplace_id] => ATVPDKIKX0DER
        )

)
```

Am I passing the information in the payload incorrectly? The error says Class 'null' not found, but I am passing all the parameters inside **$apiInstance->confirmShipment**, any help is appreciated

I tried omitting the order_items, also passing them as a nested array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to version 5.10.2 as suggested by Filip I was getting an `PackageReferenceId` error which later on was addressed by creating new protected containers first then adding the data instead of just passing arrays to them. The code below is a little more detailed than what is available in github:

```php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
    
use SellingPartnerApi\Api\OrdersV0Api;
use SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentRequest;
use SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\PackageDetail;
use SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentOrderItem;
    
$order_id = 'your_order_id_here';
$order_items_list = $this->fn_GetOrderItems($order_id);
$order_item = $order_items_list->getPayload()->getOrderItems();
            
$shipment_items_array = array(); 
    
foreach ($order_item as $item) {
    if( $item['quantity_shipped']> 0) {
        echo "Items in order " . $order_id . " already marked shipped";
        return;
    } else {
        $shipment_items = new ConfirmShipmentOrderItem();
        $shipment_items->setOrderItemId($item->getOrderItemId());
        $shipment_items->setQuantity($item->getQuantityOrdered());
        $shipment_items_array[] = $shipment_items;
    }
}
    
$package_details = new PackageDetail();
$package_details->setCarrierCode('your_carrier_code');       
$package_details->setCarrierName('your_shipping_carrier');
$package_details->setTrackingNumber('your_tracking_number');
$package_details->setShippingMethod('your_shipping_method');
        
$package_details->setPackageReferenceId('1');
$package_details->setShipDate(gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'),strtotime('your_ship_date')); 
$package_details->setOrderItems($shipment_items_array);
    
$payload = new ConfirmShipmentRequest();
$payload ->setPackageDetail($package_details);
$payload ->setMarketplaceId('your_market_placeid');
    
$apiInstance = new OrdersV0Api($this->config); //your config settings
    
try {
    $apiInstance->confirmShipment($order_id, $payload);
    echo "Order " . $order_id . " Fulfilled";
    return; 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $order_id . ' Exception when calling OrdersV0Api->confirmShipment: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed in version 5.10.2

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information, I just ran "composer require jlevers/selling-partner-api" to make sure I have the latest and it says "Using version ^5.10 for jlevers/selling-partner-api"

I got exactly the same error. Did I update it correctly? or what I am missing. By the way thank you for responding, I have been trying to figure this out for a long time

Comment: Try tu use composer update jlevers/selling-partner-api

Comment: Thank you, this issue was driving me nuts, I really appreciate your help, I had to use -w option to push the update: composer update -w jlevers/selling-partner-api

Comment: Hi Filip, sorry to bother you again, I am now getting an error regarding the **PackageReferenceId** : Exception when calling OrdersV0Api->confirmShipment: [400] { "errors": [ { "code": "InvalidInput", "message": "PackageReferenceId: is invalid, must be a positive numeric value.", "details": "" } ] } - the package id is being passed like this `[package_reference_id] => 2268` what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi @RGomez you can set "1". Probably you have one package for the shipment.

Comment: it didn't work, same error "PackageReferenceId: is invalid, must be a positive numeric value." This is what I am passing based on your suggestion `Array
(
    [package_reference_id] => 1
    [carrier_code] => FedEx
    [shipping_method] => Ground
    [tracking_number] => 6xxxxx481905
    [ship_date] => 2024-02-29T07:41:45-00:00
    [order_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [order_item_id] => 95235188738801
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

        )

)`

Comment: This code works ok:  

    `$CSItem = new \SellingPartnerApi\Model\OrdersV0\ConfirmShipmentOrderItem();  
    $CSItem->setOrderItemId(XXXXXXXX'); //<--amazon item id  
    $CSItem->setQuantity(1);  
    $PD = new PackageDetail();  
    $PD->setCarrierCode('GLS');  
    $PD->setCarrierName('GLS');  
    $PD->setTrackingNumber('1234567890ABCD');  
    $PD->setPackageReferenceId('1');  
    $PD->setShipDate(gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'));  
    $PD->setOrderItems([$CSItem]);`

Comment: Thank you Filip, I was passing the data in the form of array, the way you have it worked. I have one additional question, how do you set ConfirmShipmentOrderItem when an order has more than 1 item and both shipping in the same package?

Comment: setOrderItems([$item1, $item2, ...])